# Listening for LogCat Entires made by my own application

Tags: java, android, logcat, android-logcat

Am I able to listen for messages being places into the LogCat by my own application?

For example something like...

```
// Somewhere in my application (on a background service):
Log.i("myModule", "Something been done");
```

and....

```
    // Somewhere else something like... 
    LogCatListener logCatListener = new LogCatListener()
    {
       public void onInfoRecieved(String tag, String message)
       { 
          //Do whatever you want with the message
       }
    }
```

I'm an Android noob so be gentle with me!

Thanks.

Comment: You can still retrieve from the logging system those messages actually logged by your app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately it looks like you directly can't do that for typical Log calls (`.d`, `.i`, `.w`). If you look at the source code of the `Log` class (https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/android-4.3_r2.1/core/java/android/util/Log.java) you'll see that these calls are just translated into a `println_native`, a private function mapped to a native implementation.

Also, the Log class is final, so you **can't** extend it and hook into `.d` , `.i` , `.e`, `.w`

I'm afraid your only solution is to write a `Log` class wrapper if you need to capture those calls. This will work for your custom Log's but obviously not for the system-issued calls to the `Log` class.

But good news is there's a special `Log` function that allows listeners. There's a funny method on the `Log` class:

```
 public static TerribleFailureHandler setWtfHandler(TerribleFailureHandler handler)
```

And you can set a handler that will be called when you do

```
   Log.wtf (TAG, message)
```

funny google method names :)